# Imagick is not working on ubuntu

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

I am trying to run this code on my localhost http://buffernow.com/demo/html2image.php
on live it works fine but on my local when I click on snapshot it says imagick is not found. even though I install imagick, imagemagick from terminal. php -m shows imagick install in terminal but phpinfo(); dosent show anything. I search everywhere cant find anything helpful.
Let me know if anybody have any solution

This is the code I am trying

```
$im = new imagick('temp.pdf');
$im->setImageFormat( "jpg" );
$img_name = time().'.jpg';
$im->setSize(300,200);
$im->writeImage($img_name);
```

I am getting this "Fatal error: Class 'imagick' not found in /home/nhp06/htdocs/html/html2image.php on line 27"

Comment: what was the error ?

Comment: Fatal error: Class 'imagick' not found in /home/nhp06/htdocs/html/html2image.php on line 27

Comment: Please provide some more information. This much information is not sufficient to answer. but try with `\Imagick`

Comment: on command prompt it show "imagick" only

Comment: still same error Class 'Imagick' not found

Comment: Try to restart server `sudo service apache2 restart` and then try @UsamaSaeed

Comment: i do nothing but nothing helpful